# Worklight v6.1 - Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am using Worklight 6.1.0.1 with IBM Mobile Test Workbench 8.5.1.2. I am trying create a Test Workbench project for my app Worklight, following the docs (https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.mobtest.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_wl_creating_mobile_test_project_from_wizard.html), but not appear the option for create "IBM Mobile Test Workbench"

Comment: Can you mention the steps you took to create a Worklight project and then a Test Workbench for it? just want to see if you might have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that MTWW is really installed in your Eclipse shell. MTWW has a different installation that WL Studio (please read https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Finstall_config%2Ft_install_imtww.html)

Comment: Yes. I installed by Eclipse Marketplace "IBM Mobile Test Workbench 8.5.1.2 for Worklight"